# How to fix 2D Array that prints as one column

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

so this is what my code actually looks like, i was trying to make a simple 2d 10 by 10 array  with just zeros at first.  The zeros print in one column with breaks where a new column should be starting

```
   int[][] board = new int[10][10];

   for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
   {
       for(int y=0; y<10; y++)
       {
           board[x][y]=0;
       }
   }

   for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
   {
       for(int y=0; y<10; y++)
       {
           System.out.println(board[x][y] +"");
   }
       System.out.println("");
   }
```

it prints like this...

```
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0

       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
```

etc.
I've tried other formats, they usually come out the same.

I want it to look something like...

```
       0000000000
       0000000000
       0000000000
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using println, notice the ln suffix, indicates it adds a \n (new line) or \r (carriage return) or something similar causing a new line.

You will need to use a similar but seperate print function to print without the new line, like print.

So replace

```
System.out.println(board[x][y] +"");
```

with

```
System.out.print(board[x][y] +"");
```

This will print the positions in rows. But you will need to add a carriage return between each row. Which you already did with this line:

```
System.out.println("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a StringBuilder and build line by line, then print.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
      sb.append(" " + board[x][y]);
   }

   System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
{
   for(int y=0; y<10; y++)
   {
       System.out.println(board[x][y] +"");
}
   System.out.println("");
}
```

should be

```
for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
{
   for(int y=0; y<10; y++)
   {
       System.out.print(board[x][y] +" ");
}
   System.out.println("");
}
```

bye

Answer (score 0):

In your code you used `println` which will give output per line. Use `print` instead. Also I have removed `+""`

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){             
    for(int j=0; j<10;j++){
        System.out.print(board[i][j]);    
    }
    System.out.println("");
 }
```